# See which method is being called – xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

I have an `imagepickercontroller` and an `imageview`. When the orientation changes the `imageview` changes position. When the `imagepickercontroller` is loaded from landscape mode, the orientation changes to portrait (since `imagepicker` only supports portrait mode).

Then when the imagepicker is dismissed the imageview changes position to a place I dont want it to. 
I want to see which method is being called.

Is there a way to see which method is being called while the app runs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use break point Or you can just simply track it from your debug navigator.

Comment: but how do I track it from the debug navigator? it's just white when I'm running it

Comment: Each time the imagepickercontroller will dissmiss the viewwillappear of the controller containing imagepicker will called.From there too you can navigate to the method that's creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to track all Objective-C messages
(from ["Dave Dribin's Blog - Tracing Objective-C messages"](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/)):

> If you set the `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` environment variable to
>   "YES", the Objective-C runtime will log all dispatched Objective-C
>   messages to a file named `/tmp/msgSends-<pid>`.

This works with OS X applications and with iOS apps running in the Simulator.
To set the environment variable, choose "Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme"
and select the "Arguments" tab.